# Choose wallpaper instead of choosing live wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, live, wallpaper

In Android there is a very convenient way of getting the user to choose and set a live wallpaper.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a similar way for user to choose and set a wallpaper instead (or better yet, allow them to choose wallpaper/live wallpaper/gallery)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void chooseWallpaper() {

final Intent pickWallpaper = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(pickWallpaper, getText(R.string.chooser_wallpaper));
startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_PICK_WALLPAPER);
}
```

Comment: Where is this REQUEST_PICK_WALLPAPER?

Comment: This seem to work (since I don't need the result): startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER), getText(R.string.wallpaper)));

Comment: REQUEST_PICK_WALLPAPER is an integer,any integer as you wish.

Comment: @LimThyeChean yes,REQUEST_PICK_WALLPAPER is just to get the result.StartActivity method is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void setIt(){

Context c = this.getBaseContext();
Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), "your_array");
c.setWallpaper(bp);
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether I get you - WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER allows user to choose an available live wallpaper, I am looking for a way to choose an available wallpaper (not creating my own).